# replace \n\t pattern in a file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, ksh

ok I have a recordset that is pipe delimited

I am checking the number of delimiters on each line as they have started including | in the data (and we cannot change the incoming file)

while using a great awk to parse out the bad records into a bad file for processing we discovered that some data has a new line character (\n) (followed by a tab (\t) )

I have tried  sed to replace \n\t with just \t but it always either changes the \n\t with \r\n or replaces all the \n (file is \r\n for line end)

yes to answer some quetions below...

files can be large 200+ mb

the line feed is in the data spuriously (not every row.. but enought to be a pain)

I have tried

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\t/\t/g' Clicks.txt >test2.txt

sed 's/\n\t/\t/g' Clicks.txt >test1.txt
```

sample record

12345|876|testdata\n
\t\t\t\tsome text|6209\r\n

would like 
12345|876|testdata\t\t\t\tsome text|6209\r\n

please help!!!

NOTE must be in KSH (MKS KSH to be specific)

i don't care if it is sed or not.. just need to correct the issue...

several of the solutions below woke on small data or do part of the job...

as an aside i have started playing with removing all linefeeds and then replacing the caraige return with carrige return linefeed.. but can't quite get that to work either

I have tried TR but since it is single char it only does part of the issue

tr -d '\n' test.txt
leave me with a \r ended file....

need to get it to \r\n (and no-no dos2unix or unix2dos exists on this system)

Comment: on cmdline, for enter use `ctrl-v enter` instead of `\n`.

Comment: will that work in a script as well?

Comment: Is this `\n` spurious (in normal line data)? Or is this `\r\t\n` as a line ending? sed is line-based so dealing with `\n` is always difficult.

Comment: it should. you can also try `todos` command to change the file to unix-style if that would help.

Comment: sed is NOT for doing anything that spans multiple lines. All of it's constructs for attempting to do so became obsolete in the mid 1970s when awk was invented. Edit your question to show input that produces more than one line of output if such a thing exists and clairfy if those `\n`s and `\t`s in your sample input/output are literal tabs and newlines or not. It LOOKS like what you really want is to remove every `\n` that isn't immediately after a `\r` but idk...

Comment: Yes they are tabs and newlines... And yes remove any newline not after a Carriage return

Comment: It seems to me that Ed Morton's `awk` answer should work, as should Walter A's (now fixed with the `g` option); if you're not using GNU `sed`, however, 
you must use _literals_ in lieu of escape sequences `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

If the input file is small (and you therefore don't mind processing it twice), you can use

```
cat input.txt | tr -d "\n" | sed 's/\r/\r\n/g'
```

Edit:
As I should have known by now, you can avoid using cat about everywhere.
I had reviewed my old answers in SO for UUOC, and carefully checked for a possible filename in the tr usage. As Ed pointed out in his comment, `cat` can be avoided here as well:

The command above can be improved by

```
tr -d "\n" < input.txt | sed 's/\r/\r\n/g'
```

Comment: Clever solution; while it potentially removes more `\n` instances than the OP asked for, it's probably fine. Note that the use of escape sequences `\r` and `\n` requires _GNU_ Sed.

Comment: All else aside, lose the UUOC by changing `cat input.txt | tr -d "\n" ` to `tr -d "\n" < input.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you are trying to do but given this input file:

```
$ cat -v file                                                
12345|876|testdata
        some text|6209^M
```

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n"} {gsub(/\n/,"")} 1' file | cat -v
12345|876|testdata      some text|6209^M
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS. Alternatively with any awk:

```
$ awk '{rec = rec $0} /\r$/{print rec; rec=""}' file | cat -v
12345|876|testdata      some text|6209^M
```

The `cat -v`s above are just there to show where the `\r`s (`^M`s) are.

Comment: If i am reading this right with the the \r you are replacing carraige returns... i need the "extra" newlines gone.. i need the carriage returns line feeds.

Comment: You are not reading it right. No need to guess what the script is doing though - just look at the input/output I posted. I even piped it to `cat -v` so you can clearly see the `\r`s as `^M`s. Is there something about it that's not clear? Try it for yourself and let me know if it behaves undesirably in some way.

Comment: the awk command gives the following error: awk: line 0 (NR=82549): insufficient memory for string storage

Comment: I like to understand and learn.. so hence my question... i may want to use this for other purposes.. so please forgive my questions

Comment: No problem at all with getting questions. There are 2 awk commands in my answer. Which one is giving that error message? Which version of awk are you using? My GUESS is that you were running the 2nd awk command and also that you actually do NOT have any `\r`s in your input file and that's why the command just keeps accumulating lines as a single string until it runs out of memory. When you run `cat -v` on your input file do you see any `^M`s? It's also possible you are using an awk that doesn't translate `\r` correctly - try using a literal control-M in place of the `\r`.

Comment: Kinda. TECHNICALLY `\n` is actually a "Line Feed" and `\r` (aka control-M or `^M`) is a "Carriage Return" while a "Newline" is whatever combination of them represents an end-of-line in your system but we commonly do refer to `\n` as a newline. My script is NOT making any modifications at all to `\r`s, it's just removing any `\n`s that are not immediately preceded by a `\r`.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note that the solution below reads the input file *as a whole* into memory, which won't work for large files.

Generally, [Ed Morton's `awk` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334049/45375) is better.</sup>

Here's a **POSIX-compliant `sed` solution**:

```
tab=$(printf '\t')
sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}' -e "s/\n${tab}/${tab}/g" Clicks.txt
```

Keys to making this POSIX-compliant:

- POSIX `sed` doesn't recognize `\t` as an escape sequence, so a *literal* tab - via variable `$tab`, created with `tab=$(printf '\t')` - must be used in the script.
- POSIX `sed` - or at least BSD `sed` - requires *label names* (such as `:a` and the `a` in `ba` above) - whether implied or explicit - to be terminated with an actual newline, or, alternatively, terminated implicitly by continuing the script in the next `-e` option, which is the approach chosen here.
- `-e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}'` is an established Sed idiom that simply "slurps" the entire input file (uses a loop to read *all* lines into its buffer first). This is the prerequisite for enabling subsequent string substitution *across* input lines.
- Note how the option-argument for the last `-e` option is a *double-quoted* string so that the references to shell variable `$tab` are expanded to *actual* tabs before Sed sees them. By contrast, `\n` is the *one* escape sequence recognized by POSIX sed itself (in the *regex* part, not the *replacement-string* part).

Alternatively, **if your shell supports [ANSI C-quoted strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)** (`$'...'`), you can use them directly to produce the desired control characters:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}' -e $'s/\\n\t/\\t/g' Clicks.txt
```

Note how the option-argument for the last `-e` option is an ANSI C-quoted string, and how *literal* `\n` (which is the one escape sequence that *is* recognized by POSIX Sed) must then be represented as `\\n`. By contrast, `$'...'` expands `\t` to an *actual* tab before Sed sees it.

Comment: Note that OP is using MKS. Both the ANSI strings and the here-string work in ksh93u+, but I don't know what other versions support it.

Comment: @MarkReed: Thanks; as you can tell, I've since revised my answer to provide a POSIX-compliant solution; however, https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/sh.1.asp tells me that even MKS Ksh supports ANSI  C-quoted strings (`$'...'`); by contrast, here-strings (`<<<...`) appear NOT to be supported.

Comment: `sed ':a^J$!{N;ba^J};s/\n\t/        /g' clicks.txt` where `^J` is a newline enter via CTRL+V+J, the big space could be a real tab or a `\` followed by CTRL+V+I.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: Yes, using actual newlines to terminate label names is always an option, but the goal was to keep the solution single-line, hence the multiple `-e` options. Using _actual_ tabs is too subtle for my taste - it's visually not obvious that you're dealing with tabs (as opposed to spaces), and a well-meaning editor could convert them to spaces for you.

Comment: I see; what's the error, what platform are you on, and what Sed implementation and version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all your suggestions..  After looking at all the answers..  None quite did the trick... After some thought...  I came up with

```
tr -d '\n' <Clicks.txt | tr '\r' '\n' | sed 's/\n/\r\n/g' >test.txt
```

1. Delete all newlines
2. translate all Carriage return to newline
3. Sed replace all newline with Carriage return line feed

This works in seconds on a 32mb file.

Comment: I hope I inspired you.